# ngClick within Angular ui-map infowindow calling back multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui

I have markers on a Angular ui-map (Google Maps), that open an info window when clicked. Each InfoWindow contains a form with a button that binds ngClick to a method on the controller. The issue is that I get multiple calls to the method when the info window is opened more than once.

To reproduce the bug: Open an info window and click on the button, the method on the controller is called once which is OK. Close the info window and click on the marker again, the info window is opened. Click the button, then the method is called twice, which in my eyes is a bug. Close the window, open it again and click the button, the method is called three times, and so on.

The code I use for opening the info window from my controller is:
`$scope.myInfoWindow.open($scope.myMap, marker);` which is exactly how it's done in the demo at http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-map/.

Anyone knows how this issue could be fixed?

Kind regards.

Comment: Can you provide your code? It's hard to tell if we don't see code